# Can not create user with Rails app on heroku, but works perfect on localhost

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am working through the Michael Hartl tut and this app works perfectly on the localhost but the moment I deploy to heroku it wont create a user when i submit the information.  In fact it just sits there as if I just clicked on an empty screen, no error message nor a rediret.  I looked at the heroku logs and there are no exceptions that I can see being logged.  I tried updating the controller behavior but i get the same result.  This is frustrating.

my form looks like this:

```
  <div class="main-form">  
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages'%>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: "active" %><br/>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %><br/>

    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %><br/>

    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br/>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "create my account", class: "btn btn-lg btn-default" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

my controller looks like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @title = @user.name
  end

  def create
   @title = "welcome"
   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.password_confirmation.empty? == false 
    @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
   else
    render 'new'
   end
  end

  private

  def user_params 
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
 end
```

i have also tried setting up my create method like:

```
def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
  redirect_to @user
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

neither of these methods worked?  Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: if you want to test out the app you can go to [https://sleepy-tundra-2437.herokuapp.com/](https://sleepy-tundra-2437.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the page it looks like your submit button is outside of the form definition:

[image]

Comment: thank you for looking into this.  Like so many others I am new to development and don't know how to fully utilize the manny tools out there.  Just not sure how it worked on my local env but not on heroku.